# Replicating the behaviour of iOS Mail compose interface, but view doesn't follow cursor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've been working on creating a replica of Apple's Mail compose view so that messages can be sent via API calls rather than the standard email sending that iOS uses.

So far everything is going well, however when I type in to the message body the cursor will begin to disappear under the keyboard.

I am not sure if this is related to the way I have the constraints set up or if its something else, but right now it does not work as expect.

Here is the related code I have this far for the view controller...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.bodyTextView.delegate = self;

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButton:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *sendBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(sendButton:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBarButton;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sendBarButton;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Compose Email";

    self.recipients = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (self.contactID) {
        [self.recipients addObject:@{@"contact_id":self.contactID}];
    } else {
        [self.recipients addObject:@{@"name":self.name, @"address":self.emailAddress}];
    }

    [self prepareTableView];

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (void)prepareTableView {
    if (!self.sectionTitles) {
        self.sectionTitles = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    [self.sectionTitles addObject:@"To"];
    [self.sectionTitles addObject:@"Subject"];
    [self.sectionTitles addObject:@"MessageBody"];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.sectionTitles.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell new];

    NSString *sectionTitle = [self.sectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    if ([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"To"]) {
        EmailToTableViewCell *toCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EmailToCell"];
        toCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        toCell.toTextField.text = self.name;
        toCell.toTextField.accessibilityLabel = @"Message Recipient";

        cell = toCell;
    }

    if ([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Subject"]) {
        EmailSubjectTableViewCell *subjectCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EmailSubjectCell"];
        subjectCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        self.subjectField = subjectCell.emailSubjectTextField;
        self.subjectField.accessibilityLabel = @"Message Subject";

        if (self.subject) {
            self.subjectField.text = self.subject;
        }

        cell = subjectCell;
    }

    if ([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"MessageBody"]) {
        self.bodyCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EmailBodyCell"];
        self.bodyCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        self.bodyTextView = self.bodyCell.emailBodyTextView;
        self.bodyTextView.accessibilityLabel = @"Message Body";

        if (self.messageBody) {
            self.bodyTextView.text = self.messageBody;
        }

        cell = self.bodyCell;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        return self.bodyTextView.frame.size.height + 8;
    } else {
        return 44;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITextViewDelegate

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [self scrollToCursorForTextView:textView];
}

- (void)scrollToCursorForTextView: (UITextView*)textView {
    CGRect cursorRect = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.end];

    cursorRect = [textView convertRect:cursorRect toView:self.view];
    cursorRect = [self.tableView convertRect:cursorRect fromView:textView];

    if (![self rectVisible:cursorRect]) {
        cursorRect.size.height += 16;
        [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:cursorRect animated:YES];
    }
}

- (BOOL)rectVisible: (CGRect)rect {
    CGRect visibleRect;
    visibleRect.origin = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    visibleRect.origin.y += self.tableView.contentInset.top;
    visibleRect.size = self.tableView.bounds.size;
    visibleRect.size.height -= self.tableView.contentInset.top + self.tableView.contentInset.bottom;

    return CGRectContainsRect(visibleRect, rect);
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView.contentInset;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Here's what I have for the UI...

[image: Overall UI]

[image: Constraints for UITextView]

[image: Interface builder side bar view]

And finally here's a link to a video showing what happens so far. Note that I've reduced the minimum size of the UITextView that is one of the cells in the UITableView to better get a feel for what's going on.

[Link to video of problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgz4ncpd5rgnejw/ScreenRecording_08-16-2017%2015%3A35.m4v?dl=0)

If I have missed anything that might be helpful in figuring out this problem please let me know and I'll add it to the question.

Comment: `UITableViewController` handles this automatically. Did you try removing all the manual calculations? even keyboard is handled by default in `UITableViewController`

Comment: When keyboard is visible, try to update your Email body text view bottom constraint constant to keyboard height. So that, the cursor will not go beyond key board.

Comment: @Bilal I did try it without the extra code and the cursor just disappears below the keyboard the same as in the video I posted.

Comment: @MarkReid can you share the code with us?

Comment: @Bilal It turned out that your option was correct to a degree as no additional code was really required. But I followed the directions on this site http://candycode.io/self-sizing-uitextview-in-a-uitableview-using-auto-layout-like-reminders-app/ and what seemed to fix it besides removing all the calculation code, was to redo the constraints. I can't really say why this worked other than I must have missed one when I first set them up. If you expand your answer I'm happy to accept it as the correct one given it does do it with very minor code adjustments to dynamically size the text view.

Comment: `UITextView` constraints (top, bottom, leading, trailing) looks fine and also the height constraint is >= 200. I might have missed something else.

Comment: @Bilal The only constraint change I made was the changing the bottom constraint from the UITextView to the UITableViewCell content from "bottom margin" of the UITextView to "bottom". I don't really know what the whole different between bottom margin and bottom is but that change made the difference and made it work. Your answer that it should work without extra code was what led me to look and doing it over and not keep trying to fix the code I didn't even need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewController` handles this automatically. Try removing all the additional code and calculations. Make sure your`UITextView` leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints are set.

If you use `UITableView` then you have to do all those calculations with keyboard show/hide notifications.